# How to add row values?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

```
DATE       PCODE         ACODE             TRAFFIC      DIFFERENCE
25-02-2013  S_HDFCBANK  S_HDFCBANK     15085056
24-02-2013  S_HDFCBANK  S_HDFCBANK     9118809
```

Please help me in getting the difference of traffic from two dates and adding into last column.

Comment: "last column" order by what? And does your table has more than two rows?

Comment: oder by date and yes table contains more than two rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
SQL> select dte,pcode,acode,traffic,
  2         traffic - lag(traffic) over (order by dte) difference
  3    from data
  4   order by 1, 2, 3;

DTE       PCODE      ACODE         TRAFFIC DIFFERENCE
--------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
24-FEB-13 S_HDFCBANK S_HDFCBANK    9118809
25-FEB-13 S_HDFCBANK S_HDFCBANK   15085056    5966247
```

if you have many `pcode` `acode` per date and want to treat those separately you'd need to change the analytic to

```
lag(traffic) over (partition by pcode,acode order by dte) difference
```